# Why is my PHP API payment gateway not responding?

Tags: php, api, curl, payment-gateway

I tried to get a response from an api the first function give me the response correctly but the second does not

I tried to send it with postman and it works and there is no errors with curl ...

I tried it in many faces but it does not working
the code ::

this is the code link :

https://www.mediafire.com/file/41yyjpbfg3o567f/post.php/file

this is the payment Api flow link :

https://docs.paymob.com/docs/accept-standard-redirect

Comment: Difficult to suggest anything without seeing your code.

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple, just remove the space at the starting in the `$url` :

```
$url = ' https://accept.paymob.com/api/ecommerce/orders';
```

Change this to

```
$url = 'https://accept.paymob.com/api/ecommerce/orders';
```

Rest all working fine, the output I received is below :

```
{
   "id":124526360,
   "created_at":"2023-05-26T14:52:37.742685",
   "delivery_needed":false,
   "merchant":{
      "id":748368,
      "created_at":"2023-04-17T02:22:09.851139",
      "phones":[
         "+201141138156"
      ],
      "company_emails":[
         "3ssare3@gmail.com"
      ],
      "company_name":"AMS",
      "state":"",
      "country":"EGY",
      "city":"Cairo",
      "postal_code":"",
      "street":""
   },
   "collector":null,
   "amount_cents":100000,
   "shipping_data":null,
   "currency":"EGP",
   "is_payment_locked":false,
   "is_return":false,
   "is_cancel":false,
   "is_returned":false,
   "is_canceled":false,
   "merchant_order_id":null,
   "wallet_notification":null,
   "paid_amount_cents":0,
   "notify_user_with_email":false,
   "items":[
      {
         "name":"ASC1515",
         "description":"Smart Watch",
         "amount_cents":500000,
         "quantity":1
      },
      {
         "name":"ERT6565",
         "description":"Power Bank",
         "amount_cents":200000,
         "quantity":1
      }
   ],
   "order_url":"https://accept.paymob.com/standalone/?ref=i_LRR2b0JmcFV1dmlyeUlncW5MbnhQZWFndz09X2V3b01nSnhlMmcvdk1HWllxRlRRUlE9PQ",
   "commission_fees":0,
   "delivery_fees_cents":0,
   "delivery_vat_cents":0,
   "payment_method":"tbc",
   "merchant_staff_tag":null,
   "api_source":"OTHER",
   "data":{
      
   },
   "token":"LRR2b0JmcFV1dmlyeUlncW5MbnhQZWFndz09X2V3b01nSnhlMmcvdk1HWllxRlRRUlE9PQ",
   "url":"https://accept.paymob.com/standalone/?ref=i_LRR2b0JmcFV1dmlyeUlncW5MbnhQZWFndz09X2V3b01nSnhlMmcvdk1HWllxRlRRUlE9PQ"
}
```

**UPDATED ON AUTHOR'S REQUEST**

Complete code extracted from your file. The lines I have edited has been commented for your understanding.

```
<?php
function authApi(){
    $url = 'https://accept.paymob.com/api/auth/tokens';
    $data = array('api_key' => 'ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpVeE1pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LmV5SmpiR0Z6Y3lJNklrMWxjbU5vWVc1MElpd2ljSEp2Wm1sc1pWOXdheUk2TnpRNE16WTRMQ0p1WVcxbElqb2lhVzVwZEdsaGJDSjkuSE1rMGw2RFlNY1pfX1dDQ1AxLVRvSVJQRktMRGZRQTFIUzZUbUNKbGlDNTdmQzFGLUQ0aGJNOHpmOTdvSHppYVlqQTI3bDRWUUs4MnRrd0VDejZyWUE=');
    $body = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init();
    if (!$ch) {
        die("Failed to create cURL handle");
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disable SSL certificate verification
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else{
        $response_array = json_decode($response, true); // decode the JSON response to an associative array
        global $token;
        $token = $response_array["token"]; // extract the token from the array
        orderRegister($token);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
}

function orderRegister($token) {
    /*
    This line has been edited by @KirsSudh
     ** removed space at the beginning of the string in $url var **
    */
    $url = 'https://accept.paymob.com/api/ecommerce/orders'; // the URL of the API endpoint
    $data =  array('auth_token' => $token,
                    "delivery_needed"=> "false",
                    "amount_cents"=> "100000",
                    "currency"=> "EGP",
                    /*
                     Following lines has been added by @KirsSudh
                     ** a multi-dim array has been added for debug purpose **
                     ** the array data obtained from https://docs.paymob.com/docs/accept-standard-redirect#2-order-registration-api **
                    */
                    "items"=>array(
                                (object)array(
                                    "name"=>"ASC1515",
                                    "amount_cents"=>"500000",
                                    "description"=>"Smart Watch",
                                    "quantity"=> "1"
                                ),
                                (object)array( 
                                    "name"=>"ERT6565",
                                    "amount_cents"=> "200000",
                                    "description"=>"Power Bank",
                                    "quantity"=>"1"
                                )
                    )      // the data to be sent in the POST request
    ); 
    $body = json_encode($data);

    $ch = curl_init();
    if (!$ch) {
        die("Failed to create cURL handle");
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $body);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

    $response_order = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)) {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    } else{
        $response_array_order = json_decode($response_order, true); // decode the JSON response to an associative array
        echo $response_order;
    }
}

authApi();
```